# Livewire Event not firing - Modals

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

I'm trying to create a separate component to open a modal, but my events are not getting fired.

My parent component is Admin, and the component to open a modal is AddVideo

here is my Admin Component

```
public function add() 
{
    $this->emit('addvideoModal');
 
}
```

This is the button to fire that method

```
   <x-jet-button wire:click="add">
           {{ __('+ Video') }}
   </x-jet-button>
```

This is from the AddVideoModal

```
class AddVideo extends Component
{        
    protected $listeners = ['addvideoModal' => 'render'];

    public function render()
     {  
         return view('livewire.add-video');
     }
}
```

*Note, all my components are enclosed in a single Element. Am I missing something here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

apparently need to create a new method.

```
protected $listeners = ['addvideoModal' => 'sample'];

public function sample()
{
    $this->addModal = true;
}
```